# Having common database between tests when testing Flask

Tags: flask

I am running DDL against the DB and creating an app context in the setup of each test. Is there a way to run it only once? I am using test.py to discover and run these tests.

```
class TestStuff(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app_context = app.app_context()
        self.app_context.push()
        db.create_all() # TODO remove

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all() # TODO remove
        self.app_context.pop()

    def test_lookup(self):
        dostuff()
```

By "between tests" I mean between tests in the same class as well as between test classes themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setupUpClass and tearDownClass so that expensive operations are executed only once per class

```
class TestStuff(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        db.create_all()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        db.drop_all()

    def setUp(self):
        self.app_context = app.app_context()
        self.app_context.push()

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        self.app_context.pop()

    def test_lookup1(self):
        dostuff()

    def test_lookup2(self):
        dostuff()
```

`

For setup and tear down between tests you can use [module fixtures](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.html#class-and-module-fixtures)
Any tests in the module will call the setup and tear down module only once

```
import unittest


def setUpModule():
    print('Expensive Setup')


def tearDownModule():
    print('Expensive Tear Down')


class TestStuff(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        pass


class Test1(TestStuff):
    def test_1(self):
        print('Test1')


class Test2(TestStuff):
    def test_1(self):
        print('Test1')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: What about sharing the db between multiple classes? Could you provide something for that?